# Asp.net MVC controller parameter null when action called from javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC, and trying to navigate via js to a controller action method.  The code works (as in the action method is hit), but the parameter value I am passing in is always null

js:

```
  window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Step1", "Reports")" + "/?" + rsid;
```

Controller action:

```
public class ReportsController : Controller    {

     public ActionResult Step1(int? rsid)
        {

          //do stuff
        }
}
```

The rsid parameter is always null.  I have tried various link formats, 
eg "/?rsid=[id]", "/[id]"

Do I need a custom route for the parameter to be picked up?

Or maybe annotate the action method with [httpPost] or [httpGet]?

Comment: have you tried `"@Url.Action("Step1", "Reports")" + "/?rsid=" + rsid` ?

Comment: You not providing any value for the parameter `rsid` (so it `null`)

Comment: Also, [download fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler). Its very helpful to see what parameters are sent and makes it easier to identify issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is to just name the parameter "id" since it is in the default route and call from js like this:

```
'@Html.ActionLink("Step1", "Reports", new { id = ' + rsid + ' })'

public ActionResult Step1(int? id)
{

          //do stuff
}
```

Comment: In my case parameter value (for example rsid here) are encode with javaScript encodeURIComponent() so in MVC Action return parameter has null value, I don't know why!

Answer (score 2):

No need for string concatenation. It's bug prone, as you've discovered. Simply provide an anonymous object with your route values (using [a different overload of `UrlHelper.Action`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460348%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)) and let MVC routing decide how to represent it all.

To make this fail-safe, you'll also need to make sure your URL is safe to store in a JavaScript string by wrapping it in a call to `HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode`, then rendered without HTML encoding by wrapping in `Html.Raw`:

```
window.location.href = 
 "@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Url.Action("Step1", "Reports", new{rsid})))";
```

You could simplify matters with a helper extension method (an extension on HtmlHelper seems convenient to me)

```
public static class JavascriptHelperEx
{
    public static IHtmlString QuotedJsString(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string str)
    {
        //true parameter below wraps everything in double quotes:
        return htmlHelper.Raw(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(str, true));
    }
}
```

So now:

```
window.location.href = @Html.QuotedJsString(Url.Action("Step1", "Reports", new{rsid}));
```

Comment: Yes, also still need `@Html.Raw(...` as `@` will HtmlEncode the url. `location.href` *may* handle such over-encoded url, but regular url manipulation in JavaScript will likely be completely confused (not directly applicable to OP's case)...

Comment: Yes... One option is to wrap it in helper code that will return `HtmlString` to avoid `Html.Raw` (combining answers from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8300605/how-to-encode-embedded-javascript-in-razor-view-in-asp-net-mvc-3) for example... ). I know there are couple good answers with versions I like, can't find them now.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Thx for your contributions

Answer (score 2):

You probably mapping to a default route which is: /controller/action/id. Now in your action declaration you named your parameter as rsid which will not map to id because name is different. Change your action signature to:

```
public ActionResult Step1(int? id)
```

or option b) is specify the name of your parameter from js side:

```
window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Step1", "Reports")" + "/?rsid=" + rsid;
```

Answer (score 0):

What URL does this create?

```
"@Url.Action("Step1", "Reports")" + "/?" + rsid;
```

Something like this:

```
http://server/controller/action/?123
```

There's no parameter in that URL called `rsid`, so the model binder doesn't know where to find that value.  You need to give the value a key:

```
"@Url.Action("Step1", "Reports")" + "/?rsid=" + rsid;
```

This would create something more like this:

```
http://server/controller/action/?rsid=123
```

Comment: Thanks David,  I think I discovered the issue, if I rename my controller param to id and get rid of the question mark in the url it works because it matches a default routing pattern.  So does that mean if I want to have meaningful parameter names (rather than just id) in controller actions I need to have a custom route mask for each param pattern? (or just extract the param values from the query string old-school)

Answer (score 0):

try to have a rsid after the ? so the value will map to rsid

```
window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Step1", "Reports")" + "/?rsid=" + rsidValue;
```